# Sharing colored follow-up flags with Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2011

My team has a shared mailbox on a hosted Exchange server that everyone has delegate rights to, where we triage customer requests.

The users with Outlook for Windows use colored follow up flags, and they can all see the colors. From Outlook for Mac 2011, I only see **that** a flag is set, not the colors they see.

Can my ability to see the colors be turned on with some setting?

Comment: Could you verify which protocol you are connecting to your hosted exchange service with you Mac computer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its an IMAP account, this should do it: Right click on the mailbox name in the folder/navigation pane on the left side of the main window.

[image]

Select "Data File Properties" from the context menu. Click the "Upgrade to Color Categories" button in the window that comes up.

[image]